# acronyms used in HTTP2 draft

Tags: http, http2

When I read ["5.1. Stream States" in http2 draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-06#section-5.1), I felt difficult to understand "Figure 1: Stream States" because I couldn't find a description for the acronyms used in the figure.

My guesses are:

- PP: PUSH_PROMISE
- H: HEADERS
- ES: END_STREAM
- R: response?

Are they right?

ps. I already asked this question to HTTP mailing list last month but have not get any answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the draft I read `R` = `RST_STREAM`. I guess, you got the other acronyms right...